# Android app installs but doesn't show up in app tray

Tags: android, hardware, emulation

I'm building a time logging application and i have created the main layout. 
I tried to debug my application on my phone Samsung Galaxy S and it starts fine, but if i close it and want to run it again it's not in my app drawer. It shows up in Settings->Programs->Manage and in Recent when holding down the home button.

Here is the manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.doweb.timelog" android:versionCode="1">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
            </category></action></intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8">
</uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your closing `</action>` tag in the intent-filter is in the wrong position. 
Should look like:

```
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" > </action>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"> </category>
</intent-filter>
```

That filter is a signal to the system that this activity should be visible in the app-drawer. When it's not correct or present, the activity won't be visible.

*Usually it's best to use closed empty elements to prevent this error:*

```
<intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

You're also missing a `.` in front of your activitys class. This always relates to your apps package name. It will internally be joined to `packagename` + `classname`. Therefore the dot, otherwise it would result in `com.doweb.timelogMainActivity`, which is obviously not the correct reference. So it should be `android:name=".MainActivity"`.

Comment: I noticed the dot was missing but that didn't fix it. I created a new project and just set it up again. Now it works perfectly :) but i think your solution may have worked, i don't know :)

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure it was the intent filter since that's the thing responsible for registering in the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

your activity's name like this android:name=".MainActivity", you can have a try